# insert new bullet point in autoindent mode

Tags: indentation

with autoindent mode on, when writing a short bullet point on restructuredtext file:

```
- item one
         ~
```

Then I press Enter, and I get:

```
- item one
  ~
```

but I whould like to quickly by here:

```
- item one
- 
  ~
```

so ready to fill my `- item two`

right now I have to do `ESC[enter]i[space][space]` before 
to be ready to write my item two.

### After adding the @Ralf vars:

```
:setlocal comments+=b:-
:setlocal formatoptions+=ro
```

Here the check of vars values:

```
:set formatoptions?
     formatoptions=tcqlro
:set comments?
     comments=fb:..,b:-
:print
     - toto
```

### In insert mode, enter add the `-` but indented

```
- lkdsj
      ~         <= press Enter
  - qsdfqsdf
           ~    <= press Enter
    - lqkfdjqd
             ~  <= press Enter
      - toto
```

### In normal mode `o` add the `-` but indented:

```
- lkdsj
      ~         <= press o
  -
    ~           # in insert mode but indented
```

### In normal mode `O` add the `-` not indented but line above:

```
- ~             <= 2. item added above
- lkdsj
      ~         <= 1. press O
```

Answer (score 2):

This works with the options `formatoptions` and `comments`.

Create the file `.vim/after/ftplugin/rst.vim` and add the following lines:

```
setlocal comments+=b:-
setlocal formatoptions+=ro
```

For `comments`, the `b:-` adds the the dash as a comment character that has to be followed by a blank. See `:help 'comments'` and `:help format-comments`

For `formatoptions`, the `r` inserts the comment leader when hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The `o` inserts the comment leader on hitting <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd> in normal mode. See `:help 'formatoptions'` and `:help fo-table`.

Comment: thank you, when I hit ``O`` it add a new line above when I it ``o`` it add a line below but ... indented

Comment: @user3313834 What does `set formatoptions?` print? And `set comments?` ?

Comment: set comments? return: `comments=fb:..,b:-` and formatoptions? return: `formatoptions=jtcqlro`